# Java : Mysql timestamp daylight saving bug

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have a particular table in mysql with a field `refresh_time` `Type` as `timestamp`.

In my code, I update the `refresh_time` field to a future date of next month. For that, I calculate the milliseconds for next month date using following logic :

```
periodRefresh = currentTime + MyServiceUtils.calculateNoOfDaysInMonth(currentTime)*86400000L;
```

And then the value `periodRefresh (milliseconds)` I convert to `java.sql.Timestamp` and pass it to db side to udpate the field :

```
new Timestamp(periodRefresh);
```

But what has happened was that the current date in db was `2021-04-03 15:57:13` and when the above logic was run to update the time to next month, same time, it updated the time as `2021-05-03 13:57:13` which is 2 hours less than expected.

Our server follows UTC timezone, but I see that the user was from Australia, and in that  day (4th April 2021) there was a daylight savings time in AEST. But even then it doesn't add to above as if I convert `2021-04-03 15:57:13 UTC` to AEST, it comes as `2021-04-03 01:57:13` and the daylight savings there is at 3 am.

All the above has confused me a bit with following questions:

- If I am following UTC timezones, then also does `sql.Timestamp` and `mysql` can get affected by daylight saving time?
- How is AEST daylight saving time affecting my Australia based user when I follow UTC timezone?
- Even if DST was affecting, so it should have increased/decreased time by 1 hour, but how in my case a difference of 2 hours happened?

Comment: `Timestamp` knows nothing about DST or time zones. It's essentially just a number expressing an offset from an epoch. Whatever software displays it will interpret it in the context of the locale and time zone in which it's viewed

Comment: @g00se So, when I check in mysql table, the time in the field is 2 hours less than the expected. So, what could be the possible reason behind it?

Comment: mysql has an internal logic for daylightsaving see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html use thqat

Comment: `MyServiceUtils` is wrong? Hard to say with no info

Comment: @g00se Its not about MyServiceUtils, if you see it just gives the number of days. But here the bug is in hours.

Comment: Right. Sounds like you're on top of things

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, `TIMESTAMP` datatypes are always *stored* in tables as UTC. When you put them into the database, it first translates them from your connection's `time_zone` setting to UTC. And when you retrieve them it translates them the other way. This is not true of `DATETIME` data types.

This `TIMESTAMP` behavior is handy if you have a global app. You can ask each user for their preferred time zone, and store it as a user-preference setting.

If you take a raw (seconds since the UNIX epoch in UTC) `TIMESTAMP` value and add a month's worth of seconds to it, the resulting timestamp value may be in a different daylight-time regime. So it will be translated differently.

Either

1. do your timestamp processing in MySQL, for example with

   ```
   UPDATE tbl SET periodRefresh = periodRefresh + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
   ```
2. do it all in your app and use `DATETIME`, not `TIMESTAMP`, data types (to avoid the database's time zone translation, or
3. do it all in your app and use `SET time_zone='UTC'`; on every connection.

Comment: By the 3rd option, you meant setting time_zone='UTC' as @@session.time_zone; ?

As connection setting timezone will be the server time_zone only right